# jQuery mobile: Enable Word Wrap in ListViews

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, whitespace, word-wrap

I have a listview (see photo below) that I would like to word wrap all the contents instead of adding ... to the long lines.

How is this done?

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code you have for a single list-item?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You just need to update the CSS for the `.ui-li-desc` element that holds the text in your list-item:

```
​.ui-page .ui-content .ui-listview .ui-li-desc {
    white-space : normal;
}​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Xc6PJ/

Some good documentation for `white-space`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/white-space

Here is a sample list-item from my test `listview` after jQuery Mobile has initialized it:

```
<li class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-body-c">
    <h3 class="ui-li-heading">Sample Title</h3>
    <p class="ui-li-desc">
        Sample Content Sample Content Sample Content Sample Content Sample Content Sample Content Sample Content Sample Content Sample Content Sample Content Sample Content
    </p>
</li>
```

Answer (score 5):

My suggestion would be to use a Div within the `<li>` and set the specific behavior you want rather than changing the overall behavior of the the jquery mobile css. With this you can have only the specific thing to behave the way you want.

Comment: You can do this is pure CSS as well (no need for an extra element). You just need to apply a class (or some other type of identifier) to the list-element and use that class (or whatever) in your CSS selcetor.

Answer (score 3):

Inside the `li` section add a `div` with `style="white-space:normal;"` section which forces word-wrap.

Comment: Perfect, simple and sweet solution.

Answer (score 3):

In jQuery mobile 1.4.4 this worked:

```
.ui-listview > li p {
  white-space: normal;
}
```