# jQuery Mobile 1.4.2 Wrap Listview Content

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile

I am trying to solve exact same problem like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743725/jquery-mobile-enable-word-wrap-in-listviews)

I tried the solution but didn't work for me.

```
<div role="main" class="ui-content">
  <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    <li>
      <h2>Some Heading</h2>
      <p>some description</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery: 2.0
JQM: 1.4.2

Need some help

Thanks

Comment: Add some code. Are using link items? are you using inset listview? etc...

Comment: To make the fiddle in that question work with 1.4, change the CSS to .ui-listview p {  white-space : normal !important; }, if you are using elements other than p inside your li, change the CSS selector.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Yes I am using inset listview. I have edited my post.

Comment: what @ezanker said http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/dqWM6/