# How to wrap lines in jquery mobile for dynamic created listview?

Tags: javascript, listview, jquery-mobile

Here's an answer for static html to wrap lines in listview
[jQuery mobile: Enable Word Wrap in ListViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743725/jquery-mobile-enable-word-wrap-in-listviews)

It didn't work for dynamic/javascript created listview. All lines too long in`<li><a></a></li>` will be turned into "..."

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not because it is dynamic, but because you are using jQM 1.4 and the old answer was for 1.3.

Try CSS:

```
li a {
    white-space : normal !important;
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/Xc6PJ/194/)**